# Wifi not working on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: wireless, network-manager

At first, it just shut down after some time of working, "infinitely connecting". Now after trying all pieces of advice from the internet I got even more broken wifi. The command

```
sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager
```

gives me [this](https://pastebin.com/9punqnJz) answer

```
мар 07 00:48:02 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.2491] NetworkManager (version 1.36.6) is starting... (for the first time)
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.2493] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: 10-globally-managed-devices.co>
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.2573] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.2788] manager[0x55e6eb85a030]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.2789] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7368] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7368] hostname: static hostname changed from (none) to "liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx"
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7388] dns-mgr[0x55e6eb8362a0]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=unmanaged (auto), plugin=systemd-resolved
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7431] rfkill1: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.6/0000:02:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill1) (driver rtw_8821ce)
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7448] manager[0x55e6eb85a030]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7449] manager[0x55e6eb85a030]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7494] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7518] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7545] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7569] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7585] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7590] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7592] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7593] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7710] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7711] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7711] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7717] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7827] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7828] device (lo): carrier: link connected
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7832] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7862] manager: (wlan0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
мар 07 00:48:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139284.7865] device (wlan0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
мар 07 00:48:05 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139285.3120] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
мар 07 00:48:05 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139285.3212] modem-manager: ModemManager available
мар 07 00:48:05 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139285.3217] manager: startup complete
мар 07 00:48:05 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139285.8816] device (wlan0): new IWD device state is disconnected
мар 07 00:48:05 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139285.8818] device (wlan0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
мар 07 00:48:09 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139289.0321] agent-manager: agent[1696831b37133c9a,:1.49/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/127]: agent registered
мар 07 00:48:20 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139300.7468] agent-manager: agent[275c69fc72ec79e2,:1.92/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
мар 07 00:49:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139344.4183] device (wlan0): Activation: starting connection 'mipt-ng 1' (5fb99947-bcef-4459-9700-ee75631163d5)
мар 07 00:49:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139344.4186] audit: op="connection-add-activate" uuid="5fb99947-bcef-4459-9700-ee75631163d5" name="mipt-ng 1" pid=1811 uid=1000 result="success"
мар 07 00:49:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139344.4257] device (wlan0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
мар 07 00:49:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139344.4300] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
мар 07 00:49:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139344.4336] device (wlan0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
мар 07 00:49:04 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139344.4417] device (wlan0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
мар 07 00:49:50 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139390.4772] device (wlan0): state change: need-auth -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
мар 07 00:49:50 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139390.5221] device (wlan0): new IWD device state is connecting
мар 07 00:49:51 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139391.9763] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to 'mipt-ng'.
мар 07 00:49:51 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139391.9767] device (wlan0): new IWD device state is connected
мар 07 00:49:51 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139391.9771] device (wlan0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
мар 07 00:49:51 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139391.9808] dhcp4 (wlan0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
мар 07 00:49:52 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139392.9959] dhcp4 (wlan0): state changed new lease, address=10.55.129.173
мар 07 00:49:52 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139392.9995] device (wlan0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
мар 07 00:49:53 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139393.0184] device (wlan0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
мар 07 00:49:53 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139393.0186] device (wlan0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
мар 07 00:49:53 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139393.0192] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
мар 07 00:49:53 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139393.0196] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
мар 07 00:49:53 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139393.0196] policy: set 'mipt-ng 1' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
мар 07 00:49:53 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139393.0215] device (wlan0): Activation: successful, device activated.
мар 07 00:49:53 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678139393.2794] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
мар 07 01:49:51 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678142991.3892] dhcp4 (wlan0): state changed new lease, address=10.55.129.173
мар 07 02:10:24 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678144224.0891] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
мар 07 02:12:25 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678144345.5592] device (wlan0): disconnecting for new activation request.
мар 07 02:12:25 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678144345.5592] device (wlan0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
мар 07 02:12:25 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678144345.5594] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTING
мар 07 02:12:25 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678144345.5603] audit: op="connection-add-activate" uuid="f45a7695-6dbf-476a-ade0-67c6240f3bfa" name="POCO M3 1" pid=1811 uid=1000 result="success"
мар 07 02:12:25 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678144345.7838] device (wlan0): new IWD device state is disconnecting
мар 07 02:12:25 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678144345.7839] device (wlan0): new IWD device state is disconnected
мар 07 02:12:25 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678144345.7839] device (wlan0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
мар 07 02:12:25 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678144345.7849] dhcp4 (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction
мар 07 02:12:25 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678144345.7849] dhcp4 (wlan0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
мар 07 02:12:25 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678144345.7849] dhcp4 (wlan0): state changed no lease
мар 07 02:12:25 liya-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1678144345.8281] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
```

For some reason my phone wifi duplicates:

[image: For some reason my phone wifi duplicates]

I am tired of reinstalling ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Just updated kernel to 6.2 version and everything is working now. I had 5th one.